# Flutter [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I'm sending a post api request from my flutter App to update the data of user and getting this error
**[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast**

my Code

```
_data() async {
    setState(() {
      data();
    });
  }

Future<bool> data() async {
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final key = 'token';
final value = prefs.get(key) ?? 0;
http.Response response = await http.post(
  "https://www.exmaple.com/api/user",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $value'
  },
  body: {'key1': value1, 'key2': value2},
);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
 }
}
```

the above code works when i clicked on a button. See below code

```
RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {                    
                _data();
                Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => Home()),
                    (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
              },
              child: Text('Press Me',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
            ),
```

See the ScreenShot of error [Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Pq5.png)

here is error [error in line 76](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8wu8.png)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `value1` and `value2` is `String`.

```
body: {'key1': value1.toString(), 'key2': value2.toString()},
```

Comment: converting them to string will pass the request, but isn't it a strange thing!.
using integer (or number values) in the body of a post request is something normal so why is throwing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which exactly line is throwing you error, but maybe try parsing it ?

```
var value = int.tryParse(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please use the Authentication as follows.**

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer '+$value.toString()
```

Comment: It's not Authorization problem .

Comment: I thought the $value is of type int so here you have to cast it as string. Have you checked the above solution ?